# How to find resource ID from number?

Tags: java, android, resources

I have a codebase that was built from decompiling Java and in there is a number instead (`17039369`, or `0x1040009`) of a resource (`R.string.something`).

When trying to built a release, gradle complains that it needs a string resource, so I try to find my string resrouce in `R.java`, but all numbers start with `0x7f` there, so my ID isn't there.

How can I find the resource ID from this number?

Comment: Sure the R file is file mapping between xml and java it assigns the variable as HexDecimal
However as you know all ids are static when you type findViewById (R.id.something) it means that it is a static variable. you can find the component name as field name in R.java

Comment: @BasilBattikhi yet, the value I had in my code was not in the `R.java` file (as stated in my question ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Google to search for `0x01040009` and found out that is the value for `R.string.no`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html

Other standard strings could be found there as well.